# Cannot assign value of type 'Class' to type '[Class]'

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm setting up my first Swift project, and I'm currently getting this error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'UIViewController' to type '[UIViewController]'
```

I have a sneaking suspicion this is related to all this `?` `!` business...

I thought I had the `?`s figured out and enough of a working understanding of the `!`s to get started, but when I started looking into app delegate initialization I got confused by the way they're using the `!`s. This is what I've got so far in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);
    self.navCtrlr = UINavigationController();
    self.rootVC = RootViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil);
    self.navCtrlr!.viewControllers = self.rootVC! as UIViewController; ****
    self.window!.rootViewController = self.rootVC;
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
```

Line 4 (with the ****) is the one with the problem. Initially I was using `self.rootVC as UIViewController` without the `!`, but I got an error that asked me to add the `!`, so I did. Now I get the error I'm having now. This is what my class properties look like:

```
var window: UIWindow?;
var navCtrlr = UINavigationController?();

var rootVC: RootViewController?;
```

The UINavigationController instantiation confuses me as well, to be honest... The reason we use the `?` is because we want the variable to be able to contain nil, and to not have to define it before we create the object, right? So why the `()` at the end? But I digress.

**What is the difference between `'UIViewController'` and `'[UIViewController]'`, and what can I do to make this error go away?**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.navCtrlr!.viewControllers = [self.rootVC! as UIViewController];
```

`[UIViewController]` is Array in swift

Besides,I think the `rootViewController` is the navigationController,so

```
  self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);
  self.rootVC = RootViewController(nibName: "youNibName", bundle: nil);
  self.navCtrlr = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.rootVC!);
  self.window!.rootViewController = self.navCtrlr;
  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
```